# C# Any string starting with

Tags: c#

Lets say we have a textbox and an button. And the user write table and click on button.

I want my program to accept any text that starting with "ta". So it would accept this input. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Are you using Winforms or WPF?

Comment: `StartWith("Researching please.");`

Comment: Winforms... Thank you all for answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check if string starts with specified string you can use [StartsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131452.aspx) method:

```
if(stringVariable.StartsWith("ta")) {
    // starts with ta
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let’s do this properly... :)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the supplied string begins with "ta".
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The string to test.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the supplied string starts with "ta"; false, otherwise.</returns>
    /// <remarks>The comparison is case-insensitive.</remarks>
    private static bool StartsWithTa(string value)
    {
        const string prefix = "ta";
        if (value == null)
            return false;

        return value.StartsWith(prefix, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
```